# How to refresh IE using VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, refresh

I have been trying to figure out a way to refresh internest explorer through VBA. I have a webpage I need to refresh periodicly and I need VBA or something to refresh it.
Do you guys know of a way to get VBA to refresh a webpage?

Comment: Do you mean VBA to automate a webpage from scratch and get data, or you have an instance of IE running already and you want to refresh it?

Comment: Could you stick a meta refresh on the web page itself?

Comment: Could you use GetObject to grab the instance and then use the Refresh method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use this code which applies [Early Binding](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/EarlyvsLateBinding.htm) you will need to add a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" in the Visual Basic Editor

This code will open IE, go to google, wait for the page to load completely, then refresh.

```
Sub RefreshPage()

  Dim page As New InternetExplorer      
  page.Navigate "www.google.com"
  page.Visible = True      
  Do
  Loop Until page.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  page.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: This is fine if the OP wants to create a new instance but we are yet to hear if this is the case. Also, suggest you separate the `Dim page As New InternetExplorer` into two lines

Comment: @brettdj: Why do you suggest seperating "Dim page as New InternetExplorer" onto two lines?

Comment: option infer on and then use = new instead of as new. as new is very strange. It creates a new instance when you use it. Which is pretty unpredictable.